# how to dynamically allocate memory for flexible array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic-allocation

```
#define NUMBER_OF_INFO    3

struct info
{
   int name;
   int age;
   struct address* addressInfo;
};

struct address
{
   int number;
   int building;
};
```

I have the above struct, and I want to allocate memory for a array of `struct info`, and also `struct info` has a flexible memory, each `struct info` contains certain number of `struct address`, to make it simply in this case, assume each `struct info` contains 2 `struct address`(but can not change the `struct info`has fixed number of `struct address`), then how to allocate the memory for a array of `struct info` with size `NUMBER_OF_INFO`, and each `struct info` contains 2 `struct address`, and how to free the memory after that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use std::vector and push_back or something to insert. So you can dynamically allocate the memory:

```
    struct info
    {
       int name;
       int age;
       std::vector<address> addressInfo;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use smart pointers then the allocation and deletion can look like

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

info *persons = new info[NUMBER_OF_INFO];

std::for_each( persons, persons + NUMBER_OF_INFO,
               []( info &p ) { p.addressInfo = new address[2]; } );

//...

std::for_each( persons, persons + NUMBER_OF_INFO,
               []( info &p ) { delete [] p.addressInfo } );
delete [] persons;
```

If your compiler supports the new C++ Standard then you can use an initializer with operator new as for example

```
info *persons = new info[NUMBER_OF_INFO] {};
```